# How to multiply vectors in Gurobi using Python?

Tags: python, math, gurobi

I am trying to write a linear constraint in Gurobi using Python API. Here in this picture in the first line.[image]
As the picture can't be opened, the constraint is:

y_i≥(w_j a_i-γ_j )-M(1-x_ij ),i=1,…,m,j=1,…,k

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB

A=np.array([[ 7.6 , 8 ],
            [ 3  , 2.7],
            [ 0 , 0 ],
            [ 0.8 , 0.5],
            [ 6.6,  7.4],
            [ 6.7,  7.8],
            [ 1.9 , 2.6],
            [ 3.2 , 4.6],
            [ 6.4,  6.3],
            [10 , 10]])

m = A.shape[0]#number of rows in A
n = A.shape[1] #number of cols in A
M = 100000
k=2#cluster the data points into k clusters
# create model
model = gp.Model('hyperplane clustering')
# create variables
# Create a (m,k) array of binary variables
# x[i,j]=1 means that point ai is assigned to cluster j
x = model.addMVar((m,k), vtype=gp.GRB.BINARY,name="x")

y = model.addVars(m,lb=0.0, ub=gp.GRB.INFINITY, vtype=gp.GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="y")

w = {}
for i in range(k):
    for j in range(n):
        w[i,j] = model.addVar(lb=0.0, ub=1.0, vtype=gp.GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='w_%s_%s' %(i,j))
w = gp.tupledict(w)

gamma = model.addVars(k,vtype=gp.GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="gamma")

model.update()

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(k):
        wj = w.select(j,'*')
        wjmat = np.mat(wj).T        
        Amat = np.mat(A[i,:])
        model.addConstr(y[i] > (-np.dot(Amat,wjmat) +gamma[j])-M*(1-x[i,j]))
```

I am trying to write like this. But I always got the error' Incompatible vector dimensions'
Hope someone can help me solve this. Thanks!

Comment: Which expression causes the "incompatible vector dimensions" error? What are the dimensions of the two vectors involved?

Comment: @Stef Hi, I think `model.addConstr(y[i] > (-np.dot(Amat,wjmat) +gamma[j])-M*(1-x[i,j]))` caused 'incompatible vector dimensions'. wjmat.shape=(2, 1), Amat.shape=
(1, 2)

Comment: Please provide a minimal **reproducible** example. Otherwise, it's hard to help. There are multiple missing variables in your code snippet. What is `n`? Why are you mixing `MVars` with `Vars`? Note also that you can't use numpy functions like `np.dot` with Gurobi objects. Instead, you have to use gurobi functions.

Comment: Hi @joni , I edit the question now you can run the codes in Python. Thanks for your reply. What I have trouble with is to write the first and second constraints in the picture in question above. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: So what Gurobi function should I use to multiply A[i,:] and w[j,:]

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in the comments, you can't use numpy methods like `np.dot` with Gurobi objects. And since the third constraint can't be modelled directly with `MVar`s and Gurobi's matrix interface, I'd recommend using `Var`s.

Then, simply write the dot product as a sum of products:

```py
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import quicksum as qsum

# A = ...

m, n = A.shape
k = 2
M = 100_000
model = gp.Model('hyperplane clustering')

# Variables
x = model.addVars(m, k, vtype="B", name="x")
y = model.addVars(m, vtype="C", name="y")
w = model.addVars(k, n, ub=1.0, vtype="C", name="w")
γ = model.addVars(k, vtype="C", name="γ")

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(k):
        wdota = qsum(w[j, r] * A[i, r] for r in range(n))
        # first constraint
        model.addConstr(y[i] >= wdota - γ[j] - M*(1-x[i,j]))
        # second constraint
        model.addConstr(y[i] >= -1.0*wdota + γ[j] - M*(1-x[i,j]))
```